# Domain and range of function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given that $f(x)=x+1$ is a function from $x=\{1,3,5,7\}$ to $y=\{2,4,6,8\}$,

Find the domain and range of the function $f$. Hence determine whether the function is everywhere defined and onto. Explain the answer.

I just get stuck how i need to use $f(x)=x+1$ to find the answers?

Comment: [Wikipedia is our friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29). Also, you're confusing sets and its elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression $f(x)=x+1$, replace $x$ by numbers in the set $\{1,3,5,7\}$ and check if they belong to the set $\{2,4,6,8\}$ to verifiy that $f$ is well defined. To see if it is onto check if for every element in $\{2,4,6,8\}$ you can find an element in $\{1,3,5,7\}$ such that when you replace $x$ by this element in the expression of $f$ you get the element you picked in $\{2,4,6,8\}$.

Comment: so did u mean that if every set in x add in 1 is belong to the set y then it is onto function?

Comment: @Bilis No, if this is the case then the function is "everywhere defined" (or "well defined" in other words).

Answer (score 1):

Domain: $\{1,3,5,7\}$

Range: $\{2,4,6,8\}$

The domain is easy to see (if not, then you need to read your book or put some effort into the problem). The given range is because for $x \in \{1,3,5,7\}$ we see that we have the following for $f(x)$:
$$
1 \mapsto 2\\
3 \mapsto 4\\
5 \mapsto 6\\
7 \mapsto 8
$$
Thus, we can see that $f(x)$ is onto because every element in the codomain (i.e., the range) is being mapped to by some element in the domain.

Comment: and so it is one to one and everywhere defined right?

Comment: @Bilis It is one-to-one but for a different reason. And as Surb said, it is well-defined or "defined everywhere" as you put it.

Comment: ok i understand, thanks ya!